# CSS Vertical Float Technique

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to have a vertical float working by analogy with the horizontal one? In the Html below I'd like the green button to be as it is and the yellow to float to the bottom beyond gray shape edge.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <table style="margin: 250px; width:50px; height: 100px; background-color: #ccc; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                <div style="margin-top:-20px; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: Green;">Top</div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:-20px; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: Yellow;">Bottom</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 1** - here's a bit closer to realm picture of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm looking for a vertical uniform panel, i.e. the distance between its children should be the same. I managed to do it with the horizontal layout, but got stuck to the vertical implementation.

Html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <table style="margin: 250px; width:70px; height: 400px; background-color: #ccc; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: Gray; padding: 5px;">
               <!-- <div style="margin-top:-20px; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: Green;">1</div>-->
                  <div style="margin: -20px auto auto auto; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: white;">Top!!!</div>

                <div style="margin: auto auto -20px auto; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: white;">2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: Gray; padding: 5px;">
                <div style="margin: auto auto -20px auto; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: white;">3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: Gray; padding: 5px;">
                <div style="margin: auto auto -20px auto; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: white;">4</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: Gray; padding: 5px;">
                <div style="margin: auto auto -20px auto; width:50px; height: 40px; background-color: white;">5</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using relative position and and set the bottom as the negative of the box height

http://jsfiddle.net/e9uet/

Comment: upvote and tick the thing beside the question if you found the answer helps you.

Comment: @wizztjh very good! I'll mark at as answer anyway, but could you have a look at the updated question?

Comment: @V413HAV , yes. I am to lazy to separate the style to css. what he meant is , it is not a good idea to put css in styl="" should put it in css and <link href="myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: @user1514042 , try to clean it up in the http://jsfiddle.net/e9uet/ , by moving the style to css , it is hard for me to look at the html after you edit

Comment: One thing that would be useful is having `box-sizing: border-box` set the height of elements, similar to having the `width: auto` element's width filling the rest of the width.

Answer (score 3):

If they don't always have to be in top-down 1st-to-last order did you try simple inline-blocks?  That should allow them to fill out horizontally and then wrap vertically when not enough space.

```
.columns .icon { display: inline-block; width: 80px; height: 80px; background-color: lightblue; margin: 10px }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JT3La/