# CSS , is it possible to align elements verticaly like the windows desktop icons behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using bootstrap 3.1.1 - although that might be my irrelevant to my question.

I want to float `<div>` inside a container vertically, exactly like the behavior of windows icons on the desktop.  If there are too many icons for 1 column, they should be pushed to anew column.

Is there a method to do this with CSS or do I need a javascript helper?

example

```
<div class='container'>

<div class='icon'> 1 </div>
<div class='icon'> 2 </div>
<div class='icon'> 3 </div>
<div class='icon'> 4 </div>
<div class='icon'> 5 </div>
<div class='icon'> 6 </div>

</div>

<style>
    .container{
        width:100%;
        max-height:200px;
    }
    .container.icon{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        /*..unknow !..*/
    }
</style>
```

thanks :)

---

---

**CURRENT SOLUTION :**

As i couldnt find any css solution. i wrote a littel js helper to do it
i will share it here for future googler, let me know what you think

```
<div class='col-xs-9 stretch' id='desktop-icons'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='app-icon'>1</div>
    <div class='app-icon'>2</div>
    <div class='app-icon'>3</div>
    <div class='app-icon'>4</div>
    <div class='app-icon'>5</div>
    <div class='app-icon'>6</div>
    <div class='app-icon'>7</div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var icons=$('#desktop-icons >.row>.app-icon');
  var slice =icons.length
  var colMax=3;

  if(slice > 1){
    console.log('slicing '+slice+' icons'+'into pair of '+colMax);
    for(var i = 0; i < slice; i+=colMax) {
      console.log('wrapping '+(i)+','+(i+colMax));
      icons.slice(i, i+colMax).wrapAll("<div class='col-xs-2'></div>");
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: this will make icons stack horizontal not vertical

Comment: See answer for similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925157/css-columns-with-left-right-flow

Comment: maybe this is what you mean..


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576458/css-vertical-float-technique

Comment: @wardha-Web yp similar behavior im after, yet this answer doesn't actually do the trick, as it will not separate into columns when max width is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible with pure CSS. Seems like a fun job for little jQuery plugin. Consider this sketch I coded:

```
$.fn.iconizer = function(options) {

    options = $.extend({
        selector: '.icon',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginLeft: 10
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        var $container = $(this),
            $icons = $(options.selector, $container),
            containerHeight = $(this).height(),
            iconHeight = $($icons[0]).height(),
            iconWidth = $($icons[0]).width(),
            numberFit = Math.floor(containerHeight / (iconHeight + options.marginTop)),
            top = 0,
            left = 0;

        $icons.each(function(i) {
            if (i % numberFit == 0 && i > 0) {
                top = 0;
                left += iconWidth + options.marginLeft;
            }
            top = top + options.marginTop;
            $(this).css({
                top: top,
                left: left + options.marginLeft
            });
            top += iconHeight;
        });
    });
};

$('.container').iconizer();
```

It's pretty tiny and basic, feel free to extend it.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5snv/

Comment: one small edit i made, was using of outerHeight and outerWidth for icons, and use of innerHeight for container, this make sure icons does not over lap, nor overflow. +1 great code

Comment: Sure, there are probably much room for improvements. Feel free to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div style="transform:rotate(270deg);">
  <div style="transform:rotate(90deg);">top</div>
  <div style="transform:rotate(90deg);">bottom</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5XKp/

Comment: where does that fit ?

Comment: Not sure how rotating the text adjusts the number of columns or how things align vertically

Comment: It does not rotate the text.

Comment: @MomenMElZalabany by changing `rotate` to a `rotate3d` you can get the desired result, but sometimes it blurs the content http://jsfiddle.net/Sam88/A5XKp/1/

Answer (score 0):

for firefox/chrome/safari you can use pure css3

```
.container { column-count: 3; column-gap: 20px;}
```

This will create automatic 3 columns, 20px gap between them.
For IE, i know not.

Comment: thanks, yet this will divide container equally, this is not what im actually after.

Comment: perhaps with a very long height you can achieve what you need. Else, i think you must find a js solution (althoug my css knowledge is not to advanced)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, without javascript, force a content to fit a dynamic space like you need.
However Andrew's reply it's a good solution if you "hack" first column with an image that fits your div for maximum height (edit w3c example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count
adding after `<div class="newspaper">` following code: `<img src="hidden_marker_image.gif" height="500" width="1"><br>`

column-count it's not supported by IE9 and lowers.

Of course if you don't know available vertical space you have you need at least a javascript that return this number ad assign to the hidden_marger_image proper size. However if you choose javascript a better solution needs to implement a "display: table" (table-row, table-cell) behaviour.

Comment: thanks, i added a js solution in question that works fine in divs, let me know your opinion